# Clickhouse neighbor inconsistent result

Tags: sql, clickhouse

So in my table i have some holes between days and i am trying to get the next date that i have data. To achieve that purpose i am using the `neighbor()` function, but for each run the output changes and i don know why! Here are two screenshots of the exact same query and the two distinct outputs:

- **This was the expected result, so all the dates get the next date and the interval between them** [image]

---

- **This is after run the exact same query and the two first records does not have any neighbors** [image]

I just searched for something that could help me and i could not find the solution to this problem. BTW the source table *StockHistory* is using the ReplacingMergeTree engine.

Comment: is `clickhouse-client` show the same result?

Comment: @Slach it also happens the exact same thing

Comment: from documentation > Only returns neighbor inside the currently processed data block.

read https://www.perplexity.ai/search/ffc5d544-2827-4071-964d-edd867bb3d83, i hope it explain what data block means

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says that "The order of rows during calculation of neighbor() can differ from the order of rows returned to the user. To prevent that you can create a subquery with ORDER BY and call the function from outside the subquery."

It could be worth imposing an order by in a subquery before using the window function.

Comment: I solved my problem using the methods `lagInFrame` and `leadInFrame` instead of `neighbor`, thanks for the explanation btw.